# Can't connect to mongodb.Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

while trying to connect with mongodb i'm getting this error :

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common 
reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\Node-Jonas\Node-Projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:828:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\Node-Jonas\Node-Projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node-Jonas\Node-Projects\server.js:21:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00-g4ttz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-01-g4ttz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

i already whitelisted my ip but still getting the problem.also can't connect to compass. it was all fine even yesterday and so don't know why all of suuden this problem occured.need help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might your are using vpn or proxy some times!! Try to whitelist your access from anywhere! So you can alwasys access your atlas

Comment: Thanks for your reply.and i just checked thats there's no vpn or proxy running behind the scene.also i whitelisted my current ip within "any ips" 0.0.0.0/0"

Comment: did your problem solve after whitelisted within any ip?